# GWT Launcher error because of huge classpath

Tags: eclipse, gwt, launcher, app-launcher

I am trying to run an GWT application which (unfortunately) has a huge classpath, because if which the GWT launcher fails to load and I get the following error :

```
CreateProcess error=87, The parameter is incorrect.
```

Does somebody know a workaround for this solution ?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugly and temporary workaround is to move you working folder closer to the HDD root.

We had the same problem using Datanucleus. The other workaround was to set the builder so that it only enhanced the desired classes.

But there again as the project grows bigger we might encounter the same problem again.

Answer (score 1):

What OS are you using?

If this is Windows Xp or later, the maximum length of a java command (or a CLASSPATH value) [would be **8191**](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;830473&x=7&y=13).
And this [thread illustrates the result](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=tree&goto=493531&#page_top) (an error like the one you have).

If you are at the limit, you can try to build the CLASSPATH separately from the java command, as suggested in [Java Glossary page](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/classpath.html#LONGCOMMANDLINE).